# Loop over character vectors and use elements as column names within lambda function

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rlang, non-standard-evaluation

I would like to loop over a vector of variable names with `purrr`, then use the variables inside a function with `dplyr`, as with the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

#creating index
index<-c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')

#mapping over index with lambda function
map(index, ~iris %>% filter (.x > mean(.x)))
```

I was expecting to see a list of two data.frames, as in

```
list(Sepal.Length = iris %>% filter (Sepal.Length > mean(Sepal.Length)),
     Sepal.Width = iris %>% filter (Sepal.Width > mean(Sepal.Width)))
```

Is there a way to use the `.x` variables as column names within the data.frames in the lambda function?

I think it may have something to do with data masking and non-standard evaluation, and I suspect `rlang` may be helpful here, but I am not familiar with the subject.
Thank you

Comment: Very interesting GuedesBF. Could you please elaborate in which situation we could use this procedure. What is the idea behind. I really want to know?? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, @TarJae, thank you. I have a dataset with 300+columns, including a `dummified` grouping variable spread over several columns, and several other `data` variables. I would like to `summarise(across(data_variables, ~something)` for every group defined by `dummy_x==1`, `dummy_y==1`, so a vector of `c("dummy_1", "dummy2"...)` could help determine the variables beforehand. The question aimed to understand the procedure as in the first of akrun's answers, which could make things easier.

Comment: The actual procedure is a bit more complex, but I used a minimal reprex for the exact `vector of characters as variable names` issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are strings.  We need to convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
out <- map(index, ~iris %>%
       filter (!! rlang::sym(.x) > mean(!! rlang::sym(.x))))
names(out) <- index
```

-output

```
> str(out)
List of 2
 $ Sepal.Length:'data.frame':   70 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:70] 7 6.4 6.9 6.5 6.3 6.6 5.9 6 6.1 6.7 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:70] 3.2 3.2 3.1 2.8 3.3 2.9 3 2.2 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:70] 4.7 4.5 4.9 4.6 4.7 4.6 4.2 4 4.7 4.4 ...
  ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:70] 1.4 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.6 1.3 1.5 1 1.4 1.4 ...
  ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Sepal.Width :'data.frame':   67 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:67] 5.1 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.9 5.4 4.8 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:67] 3.5 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 3.1 3.7 3.4 ...
  ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:67] 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.6 ...
  ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:67] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.2 ...
  ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

-testing with OP's expected

```
> expected <- list(Sepal.Length = iris %>% filter (Sepal.Length > mean(Sepal.Length)),
+      Sepal.Width = iris %>% filter (Sepal.Width > mean(Sepal.Width)))
> 
> identical(out, expected)
[1] TRUE
```

---

Or subset with `cur_data()`

```
map(index, ~ iris %>%
     filter(cur_data()[[.x]] > mean(cur_data()[[.x]])))
```

---

Or use `across` or `if_all`, which takes directly string

```
map(index, ~ iris %>%
           filter(across(all_of(.x), ~ . > mean(.))))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Isnt it possible to use `{{  }}` instead of `!!` ?

Comment: @GuedesBF that is used with unquoted inputs in a function.  Your inputs are strings

Comment: The `{{}}` does similar to `enquo` with `||`

Comment: ok, thanks. I am new to it, and still very confused when it comes to `rlang` and non-standard evaluation

Comment: @GuedesBF eg. when you create a function `f1 <- function(dat, colnm) dat %>% summarise(Mean = mean({{colnm}})); f1(iris, Sepal.Length)`. The input column name is not a string whereas in your case, it is a character vector whch we loop in `map`

Comment: Thanks again for the thorough explanation.

If you don't mind, I like to let the question sit around for a couple minutes before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

A solution like

```
map(index, function(i, x) filter(x, x[[i]] > mean(x[[i]])), iris)
```

seems to balance the functionality of dplyr (e.g., doing sensible things with `NA` values) without excessive encumbrances of non-standard evaluation, while also highlighting some useful R idioms like use of `[[` to extract columns by name that are likely to be useful when non-standard evaluation becomes just to cumbersome.

Personally I would use `lapply()` instead of `map()` and save myself from having to learn another package. If I wanted named list elements I'd do that 'up front' rather than adding after the fact

```
names(index) <- index
lapply(index, function(i, x) filter(x, x[[i]] > mean(x[[i]])), iris)
```

or maybe

```
lapply(setNames(nm=index), function(i, x) filter(x, x[[i]] > mean(x[[i]])), iris)
```

If this were a common scenario in my code (or even if this were a one-off) I might write a short helper function

```
filter_greater_than_column_mean <- function(i, x)
    dplyr::filter( x, x[[i]] > mean(x[[i]]) )

lapply(index, filter_greater_than_column_mean, iris)
```

If I were being a dilettante in my own way and trying to be more general, I might get overly complicated with

```
filter_by_column_mean <- function(i, x, op = `>`) {
    idx <- op(x[[i]], mean(x[[i]]))
    dplyr::filter(x, idx)
}
lapply(index, filter_by_column_mean, iris)
lapply(index, filter_by_column_mean, iris, `<=`)
```

or even

```
filter_by_column <- function(i, x, op = `>`, aggregate = mean) {
    idx <- op(x[[i]], aggregate(x[[i]]))
    dplyr::filter(x, idx)
}
lapply(index, filter_by_column, iris, op = `<=`)
lapply(index, filter_by_column, iris, `<=`, median)
```

Now that I'm not using non-standard evaluation, I might aim for base R's `subset()`, which also does sensible things with `NA`. So

```
filter_by_column <- function(i, x, aggregate = mean, op = `>`) {
    idx <- op(x[[i]], aggregate(x[[i]]))
    subset(x, idx)
}
```

I know this means I've learned a bunch of things about base R, and maybe I should instead have learned about `!!` versus `!!!` versus ..., but at any rate I've learned

- Functions like `mean` are 'first class', I can assign the symbol representing the function (e.g., `mean`) to a variable (e.g., `aggregate`) and then use the variable as a function (`aggregate(...)`).
- Operators like `<` are actually functions, and `lhs < rhs` can be written as `` `<`(lhs, rhs) `` (and to write that I had to learn how to write backticks in markdown!)

More prosaically

- The `FUN` argument to `lapply()` takes arguments in addition to the argument being iterated over. These can be named or unnamed, with the  usual rules of argument matching (match first by name, then by position) applying.
- `[[` can be used to subset by name, avoiding the need for `seq_along()` or other less robust operations that rely on numerical index.

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```
index<-c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')
df <- iris

setNames(
  lapply(
    seq_along(index),
    function(i){
       mu <- mean(df[,index[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
       df[df[,index[i],drop = TRUE] > mu, ]
    }
  ),
  index
)
```

Comment: subsetting the `index` by position inside the data.frame subsetting, with `[index[i]]` is really simple and useful. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, can be simplified to: `setNames(
  lapply(
    index,
    function(x){
       mu <- mean(df[,x], na.rm = TRUE)
       df[df[ , x, drop = TRUE] > mu,]
    }
  ),
  index
)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.data` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

index<-c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')

map(index, ~iris %>% filter (.data[[.x]] > mean(.data[[.x]])))
```